# Ensure child exits when parent does

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am spawning a child process in node and have sometimes noticed that the child process does not exit when the parent process exits.

```
  var worker = child.fork(__dirname + '/process');

  worker.on('exit', function(exitCode) {
    if (exitCode != 0) {
      start();
    }
  });

  process.on('exit', function() {
    worker.kill();
  });
```

I am also trying to ensure that if the worker dies without a 0 error code it is started again.  This seems to work just fine.  However I have noticed that sometimes my child process is left hanging around after the parent is gone.

What exactly is 'process.on('exit'...' listening for?  I.E. What happens when I press Ctrl-C, will exit pick that up?  Do I need to listen for all parent exit signals?

Should I be listening for more on the child process as well?  Like 'uncaughtException'?

Basically what is the proper way to launch a child process, ensure it stays up, but exits when the parent does?